# How to round half down in Mathematica?

Tags: numerics, precision-and-accuracy

I found [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/29122/why-do-numberform-and-round-apparently-use-different-tie-breaking-methods) and [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2116/why-round-to-even-integers/2120#2120) on this StackExchange as to why Mathematica [rounds half to even](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Round_half_to_even), which means that

```
Round[{0.5, 1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5}]
```

gives

```
{0, 2, 2, 4, 4}
```

but now I am interested in [rounding half down](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Round_half_down), which would be a function such that

```
RoundDown[{7.49, 7.5, 7.51}]
```

gives

```
{7, 7, 8}
```

I don't think it exists since I searched a lot and didn't find anything, so I was wondering as to how would one code such a function efficiently (I need to run it some millions of times)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
ClearAll[roundDown]
roundDown = Ceiling[# - 1/2] &; (* thanks: @MichaelE2 *)

roundDown @ {7.4999, 7.5, 7.51}
(* or roundDown[{7.4999, 7.5, 7.51}] *)
```

> {7, 7, 8}

Comment: That's short and efficient, thanks! As a note for future users it also works with `roundDown[{7.4999, 7.5, 7.51}]`

Comment: @viiv, my pleasure. Thank you for the accept.

Comment: @viiv One might want to use `1/2` instead of `0.5`.  E.g. try `rd1 = Ceiling[# - 1/2] &; rd2 = Ceiling[# - 0.5] &; {rd1[3/2 + 2^-53], rd2[3/2 + 2^-53]}`.

Comment: @MichaelE2, very good point.

Comment: Indeed, it's all about those edge cases. Fortunately I never went that deep into the precision, I was limited to floats.

Answer (score 2):

Adding a note to kglr's answer, consider

```
n = 50*4.65

roundDown[n]
```

> 233

An improvement could be

```
rd[n_] := Ceiling[With[{r = Round[#]}, r + Chop[# - r]] &[n - 0.5]]

rd[n]
```

> 232

Comment: But `50*4.65` equals ``232.50000000000003` ``, so shouldn't it round to `233`? What if the number is exactly `232.50000000000003`?

Comment: In practical situations I have encountered I would require `50*4.65 = 232.5`.