# Efficient Round edition with different rounding direction

Tags: machine-precision, precision-and-accuracy, rounding

As pointed out in [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2116/4742), Mathematica has a special version of `Round` that

> Round rounds numbers of the form x.5 toward the nearest even integer.

A comment by David G suggest that why not have differnt options `Direction → {"HalfDown","HalfUp","HalfEven","HalfOdd","Stochastic"}`

These days I need a version of Round to HalfUp. I write a quite ugly and slow function as below

```
myRound[x_, d_] := Module[{},
  c1 = (1./d)*10;
  c2 = 1./d;
  theDigit = Last@IntegerDigits@IntegerPart[x*c1];
  If[theDigit >= 5,
   Internal`StringToDouble@ToString@N[(IntegerPart[x*c2] + 1)/c2],
   Internal`StringToDouble@ToString@N[(IntegerPart[x*c2])/c2]]]
```

speed test

```
In[267]:= 
myRound[#, 0.01] & /@ RandomReal[1., 1000000]; // AbsoluteTiming

Out[267]= {30.7072, Null}

In[268]:= 
Round[#, 0.01] & /@ RandomReal[1., 1000000]; // AbsoluteTiming

Out[268]= {0.285921, Null}
```

So I am wondering if someone on this site already have developed an efficient toolkit for round matters?

Comment: `Floor[x+0.5]`?

Comment: @Szabolcs But Floor gives integer. Round can round at any digit

Comment: Are your aware of [RoundingRule](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ComputerArithmetic/ref/RoundingRule.html)?

Comment: @Silvia Sounds a probable solution. But I didn't quite understand the document. Would you like to post an answer?

Comment: Could extend the method proposed by @Szabolcs: `myRound[x_, d_] := d*Floor[x/d + 1/2]`

Comment: @DanielLichtblau What about the 0000000000``1 problem for example for  `myRound[8.121, 0.01]`

Comment: That's a result of using decimal values e.g. .01 that do not have exact binary equivalents. Could instead do `myRound[8.121,1/100]` and numericize afterward.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Unfortunately, this is not robust. Try `N@myRound[156.015, 1/100]`, it gives 156.01, which is wrong

Answer (score 4):

I offer the following solution

```
r2[x_, a_] := x - Mod[x, a, -(a/2)]
```

We can verify that it has the desired result, using `PiecewiseExpand`

```
PiecewiseExpand[r2[x, a], -2 a < x < 2 a && a > 0]
```

Performance is only a little slower than the built-in `Round`

```
list = RandomReal[{0, 1}, 1000000];

AbsoluteTiming[Round[list, 0.1];]
(* {0.0079, Null} *)

AbsoluteTiming[r2[list, 0.1];]
(* {0.009414, Null} *)
```

Comment: Wow, great solution. But there is a issue with hidden fractions as pointed out by https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/65298/4742 . But if we use `Internal`StringToDouble@ToString`, the performance will drop down.

Comment: I figured out a trick, though I don't know why it works. The efficient solution to hidden fraction may be `r2[x_, a_] := (IntegerPart[(x/a - Mod[x/a, 1, -(1/2)])]*10^12)/
  10.^(12 - 1/Log[a, 10])`

Comment: I just realize that your `r2` doesn't round 5 up. I mean `r2[1.265,0.01]` doesn't give 1.27. How to fix it?

Comment: @matheorem Technically, `1.265` in binary floating point corresponds to the fraction `5697053528623677/4503599627370496` which less than `1265/1000`.  The issue is due to rounding decimal to binary. Thus it is a problem of inputting the number you meant, not a problem with `r2[]`.

Comment: Hi, @MichaelE2. So how to solve the problem. I definitely need some function takes 1.265 input and gives 1.27. I am already mad with those fussy 00000002` and 999999998`. Do you have robust round function?

Comment: @matheorem Would `N@r2[Rationalize[x], Rationalize[a]]` work? It becomes less robust if `x` is the result of a computation in which rounding error has been propagated and magnifiied.

Comment: @MichaelE2 the problem of using precise computation like `Rationalize` will be too slow. I need to apply round to a very large list.

Comment: @matheorem The problem with imprecise calculation is that unwanted errors creep in, such as what you're complaining about. :)  How about this?: `r2[x_, a_] := 
 x (1 + Sign[x] $MachineEpsilon) - Mod[x (1 + Sign[x] $MachineEpsilon), a, -(a/2)]`

Comment: @MichaelE2 Still not correct. `r2[8.12, 0.01]` gives 8.120000000000001`

Comment: @matheorem Rounding error from `0.01` being converted to binary (compare `Round[8.12, 0.01 ]`). I doubt all problems can be avoided if you wish to use binary floating-point for underlying computations.

Comment: @matheorem, I think you need to consider why you know the input is exactly 1.265 rather than a little more or a little less, and why the rounding is important to you.  If you know the 3rd decimal place is exact, I suggest you multiply all your numbers by 1000, and work with integers.

Comment: @mikado Actually working with integer is also not robust. Try `IntegerPart[5.06*100]` it givse 5.05

Comment: @MichaelE2 How to use binary floating-point for underlying computations?

Comment: @matheorem That's what happens (automatically) when you use real (floating-point) numbers on all common CPUs.

Comment: @matheorem I was suggesting something like `r2[Round[1.265*1000], 10]` or `r2[Round[5.06*1000], 10]` both of which give the right answer.