# How to think about the answer to Rationalize[-11.5, 1]

Tags: numerics, language-design

In the open source *Mathematica* implementation called [Mathics](https://mathics.org), an [issue](https://github.com/mathics/Mathics/issues/1553)  was raised where Mathics computes `Rationalize[-11.5, 1]` as -12 rather than *Mathematica* which is reported to compute this as -11.

Looking at the docs for [`Rationalize`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rationalize.html), -11 seems equally valid.

Is this is purely an implementation choice, or is there more reasons why one answer is preferred over the other?

Comment: I believe `Rationalize[]` uses the continued fraction expansion to find a rational approximation with least denominator. For negative numbers it proabably returns `-Rationalize[-x]`. I don't know how Mathics does it.

Comment: `Mathics[]` uses the continued fraction expansion as well on the bounds given. Here those values are -11.5 +/- 1  When the continued fraction of both of these differs in a digit that is when it stops. However the value it picks is `min(-13, -11) + 1` which is -12. Of course, applying `-Rationalize[-x]` first in Mathics will give the answer reported .

Comment: Probably an implementation detail rather than a design choice.

Comment: Whether a design choice or not, symmetric results for `±x` seems a nice feature.

Comment: Strongly related: [(1)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2116/280), [(2)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/193412/280), [(3)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/204359/280).

Comment: `Round[-11.5, 1]` returns -12 in *Mathematica*.

Comment: Very interesting @AlexeyPopkov. Rationalize and Round clearly work differently in their rounding, but it seems for very deliberate reasons.

Comment: Is there a place to read about how far along mathics is? Like what percentage of code is implemented already?

Comment: Sort of off topic, but ``Length[Names["System`*"]]`` gives 1130 builtins; probably far fewer than you get from MMA. https://mathics.org/docs/mathics-latest.pdf has what was available the end of July. My take though is that if you aren't someone who is willing to work on this in any capacity (which doesn't mean necessarily the Python code, it could be improving docs, writing compatibility libraries for older MMA or functions in the Wolfram Language, etc.), then I suggest waiting until others get around to improving things. It is not hard to find bugs. Harder is finding people to fix them.

Answer (score 1):

Summarizing the comments to the question, Michael E2 points out that, for negative *x*, having `Rationalize[x] == -Rationalize[-x]` gives symmetric results, whether or not this was a specific design choice or an implementation detail.

So the next release of Mathics will do the same.

Alexey Popkov suggests comparing with the behavior of `Round` which is different in its behavior in that it rounds to the nearest even integer (and this clearly does not happen here). If nothing else, this circumstantial evidence suggests that the behavior choice for `Rationalize` was probably deliberate.